# Memory leak if VCL Exception object is thrown with Message

Tags: string, exception, c++builder, vcl, rad-studio

I find it hard to believe, but code that throws a VCL Exception somehow leaks memory.

Have created a MVE to convince myself that this is really happening.

So here's a basic C++ console application, using VCL, that just repeatedly throws the same exception and tries to catch it.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while (true){
        try {
            throw Exception(L"This is my Exception Message");
        } catch (const Exception & e) {
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When you run this code outside the debugger, it leaks like a seave.
If you run this code under the debugger, it leaks at a slower rate.

If you instead pass an integer (i.e. `throw Exception(42)`), there is still a leak.
At this point I was hoping to avoid the complicated dance that UnicodeString performs.

The question is: why does this leak?
Have I missed something or am I using Exception the wrong way?

Found this to happen at least with XE7.
With XE11, the leak only occurs if the exception is thrown from a subroutine.
(these are the only versions available to me).
We have the JCL library installed, if that's a factor.

Comment: Somebody asked basically the same question here, but for XE2: https://codeverge.com/embarcadero.cppbuilder.cpp/memory-leak-when-catching-exceptio/1057044

Comment: In my experience, exceptions often lead to destructors not being called for local variables (even for non-VCL classes). The solution is to update C++ Builder and stop using the classic compiler (Project Options -> C++ Compiler).

Comment: There are a few open bugs related to this problem in the embarcadero Jira website. One is RSP-27271 in quality.embarcadero.com .

Comment: With the new RAD Studio 11 and clang compiler things indeed look better than before.

Comment: @VLL care to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, exceptions often lead to destructors not being called for local variables (even for non-VCL classes). In this case, it seems destructor isn't even called for `Exception` class itself.

Possible solution is to update C++ Builder and stop using the classic compiler (Project Options -> C++ Compiler).

The exact memory leak in your question is reported fixed in version 10.3.0 ([RSP-11916](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11916)), and reported broken again (still open) in version 10.3.2 ([RSP-27271](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27271)). Another report says this only occurs in modern versions when optimizations are not enabled ([RSP-30118](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30118)).